# Turn on voltage when input is grounded

Tags: transistors, mosfet, switches

I have a new intercom that requires 12V when the ring switch is pressed, but my ring wire does not supply voltage, it just loses its resistance (it is grounded.)

What circuit do I need to turn on voltage when the input is grounded? P MOSFET? I am not an electronics engineer, so I would need a complete circuit diagram.

I have another wire (for the microphone) which delivers 12V. Maybe I can switch this voltage to the ring when the switch is pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To switch a supply voltage to a device by means of a grounded switch, you can use a P channel MOSFET. If the switch is not pressed, then the P-MOSFET is not conducting.

Something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdVmwa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: thank you very much
i will try that

Comment: I already thought that a P-MOSFET might fit. Why do you need a 1k resistor here?

Comment: Without 1K resistor, the gate would float (take some random voltage) which would make the circuit switch on/off randomly.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWgDNg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A 12 V relay provides a simple way of interfacing the old with the new.*

How it works:

- Pressing the button energises the relay.
- The relay contact can switch the 12 V supply as shown here or it can be wired in place of whatever would normally enable the new system. The advantage is that the button circuit and the new circuit can be completely isolated from each other.

You local car spares shop or electronics shop should be able to provide you with something suitable.

Comment: would you prefere a P-MOSFET or a relay?

Comment: For simplicity of wiring, testing, isolation and availability - a relay. For space, cost, silence and cool running - a MOSFET.

Comment: ok then i will prefere the MOSFET because the space in the intercom is limited. Thank you!